# Prog A calls Prog B via invoke_signed. How do I pass account_infos for the next CPI call from Prog B to Prog C?

Tags: pda, cpi

I have **Program A**. It makes a CPI call to **Program B** via ***invoke_signed***.

User makes a call to the **Program A**. These accounts will be passed to the **Program B**:

- token_program: AccountInfo<'a>
- source: AccountInfo<'a>
- destination: AccountInfo<'a>
- authority: AccountInfo<'a>

Then, I want **Program B** to make another CPI call to **Program C**. On behalf and using seeds of the **Program A**

So, the problem is - how do I pass the **Program C** account_info?
The first thought was - can I hardcode it? like:

```
let program_c = Pubkey::from_str("PubKEyHere111111...")
```

But... I'm not allowed to 'hardcode' it in **Program B**. There is no way to convert ***PubKey*** to ***account_info***. Because that's how the `Solana Runtime` works - you should pass all the ***Account_Metas*** beforehand. But, is it still a way to do that except passing it explicitly to the **Program A**?

Comment: If your question is answered. Please mark it as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accounts needed for **Program C** needs to be passed in via the CPI call made to **Program B**. Which circles back to the accounts needed for both **Program B** and **Program C** needs to be passed in when the user makes a call to **Program A**

There is no other way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Here is what I have found if someone is interested: ...Because the only way for a program to acquire AccountInfo values is by receiving them from the runtime at the program entrypoint, any account required by the callee program must transitively be required by the caller program, and provided by its caller... https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/index.html#cross-program-instruction-execution

Comment: That's a great description! It's worth putting that as an answer